# Deleting unique rows from a large database

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a database in SQL 2008 that has over 2 million rows in it (It was created from a CSV).  I'm trying to delete the rows that have unique data.  Whenever I run it, it says that there have been roughly 12000 - 13000 rows affected. How can I delete all the rows I want deleted in 1 single step instead of executing it every time? I know it's deleting rows every time b/c I run a count every so often on it.  It will take me forever at the pace I'm going at.
Can this code be modified to do what I need?

```
WITH numbered AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name, size, lastwritetime 
ORDER BY name, size, lastwritetime) 
AS _dupe_num FROM AllFiles 
WHERE name = name
AND   size = size
AND   lastwritetime = lastwritetime
)
DELETE FROM numbered WHERE _dupe_num = 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having re-read the question and understood that the poster wants to keep duplicates, here is a statement that works to keep all records that have duplicates (assuming a PK field named id):

```
DELETE af FROM AllFiles af
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM AllFiles af2
    WHERE af2.name = af.name
    AND af2.size = af.size
    AND af2.lastwritetime = af.lastwritetime
    AND af2.id <> af.id)
```

**EDIT:** If you only want to keep a single copy of each duplicate record and also delete all records that have no duplicates, use the following statement:

```
DELETE af FROM AllFiles af
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM AllFiles af2
    WHERE af2.name = af.name
    AND af2.size = af.size
    AND af2.lastwritetime = af.lastwritetime
    AND af2.id <> af.id)
OR EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM AllFiles af3
    WHERE af3.name = af.name
    AND af3.size = af.size
    AND af3.lastwritetime = af.lastwritetime
    AND af3.id > af.id)
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to get rid of duplicates, but now that I re-read your question, are you trying to do the opposite and only keep one copy of each record that has duplicates?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to keep records with duplicates.  I should clarify that the rows aren't duplicate, but the file name, size, and dates are.  I have a field called Directory as well, which is different for each of the aforementioned fields.

Comment: Do you have a primary key field in this table?  If so, what is its name?

Comment: No primary key.  The database is really just for me to narrow down some fields.  I am having a hard time opening the almost 1 GB csv file, and thought this would be easier.  Unless you want to switch gears and help figure this out in Powershell! haha

Comment: I'd recommend creating an identity PK field on the table.  If you make one named id, this works.

Comment: Ran the code.  It appears to only delete 941 rows - which could be correct - but seems small in a database of this size.  Whereas when I was running the above code, it deleted thousands at a time.  Then again the end result is to delete duplicate files from my server.
Does this code keep 1 copy of each duplicate?

Comment: This code keeps all copies of each duplicate.  If you wanted to keep one and you have other fields that may or may not be the same, how would you decide which one to keep?